# Invalid format for continuation token on Cosmos db

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Currently I try to get next result of my query at Cosmos db this is my code.

```
public async Task<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<Peterworks>>> GetMultipleAsyncPaging(string queryString, string continuesToken,
        int pageSize)
{
    var results = new List<Peterworks>();
    QueryRequestOptions queryRequestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions();
    queryRequestOptions.MaxItemCount = pageSize;

    var query = _container.GetItemQueryIterator<Peterworks>(new QueryDefinition(queryString), continuesToken, queryRequestOptions);

    FeedResponse<Peterworks> feedResponse = await query.ReadNextAsync();
    foreach (Peterworks peterworks in feedResponse)
    {
        results.Add(peterworks);
    }
    return new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<Peterworks>>(feedResponse.ContinuationToken, results);
}
```

Using this code with Asp.net core web api

API

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPageResult(string appkey, string postbackType, long startDate, long endDate, int pagesize, string continuetoken)
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<Peterworks>> returnValue;
        int pageNumber = 0;
        var query =
            $"SELECT * FROM peter_db p where p.appkey = '{appkey}'AND p.postback_type = '{postbackType}' AND p.event_time >= {startDate} AND p.event_time <= {endDate} ORDER BY p.event_time";

        if (continuetoken == "null")
        {
            string continueNullToken = null;

            returnValue =
                await _cosmosDbService.GetMultipleAsyncPaging(query, continueNullToken, pagesize);

        }
        else
        {
            string continueTokenDecode = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(continuetoken);
            var jsonContiueToken = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(continueTokenDecode);

            returnValue =
                await _cosmosDbService.GetMultipleAsyncPaging(query, jsonContiueToken, pagesize);
        }

        return Ok(returnValue);

    }
```

When token is null I get this result

```
{  "key": "[{\"token\":\"+RID:~6XYNAPAaNywkAQAAAAAAAA==#RT:1#TRC:2#RTD:EOhlC3LmlrnZoy5QrRcNBMHZH43PLA==#ISV:2#IEO:65567#QCF:7#FPC:AgEAAAAyAK8A4Hf99T7xxMAf+QH8/AF/APwPeEB/nWZk+H8A8H8ACMAA8P//A5Dw///f/v////8B\",\"range\":{\"min\":\"\",\"max\":\"FF\"}}]",
```

Using this token value I try to get next result, but this error came in.

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Exceptions.MalformedContinuationTokenException: Invalid format for continuation token "[{\\\"token\\\":\\\" RID:~6XYNAPAaNywkAQAAAAAAAA==#RT:1#TRC:2#RTD:EOhlC3LmlrnZoy5QrRcNBMHZH43PLA==#ISV:2#IEO:65567#QCF:7#FPC:AgEAAAAyAK8A4Hf99T7xxMAf QH8/AF/APwPeEB/nWZk H8A8H8ACMAA8P//A5Dw///f/v////8B\\\",\\\"range\\\":{\\\"min\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"max\\\":\\\"FF\\\"}}]" for ParallelCrossPartitionQueryPipelineStage
```

Without jsonConvert, this error came out.

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: f1a36b17-58de-44f9-9d73-ba699c38bb16; Reason: (Encountered an unexpected JSON token.ActivityId: f1a36b17-58de-44f9-9d73-ba699c38bb16, Darwin/10.16 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.19.3);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you providing this token as an input value to your method? Please edit your question and include that code.

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks for reply. I update the question.

Comment: I noticed that you're manipulation your continuation token value by doing things like `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` and then `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`. Please note that continuation token is an opaque object and you should not be manipulating it. Can you try by not manipulating its value. You should use the continuation token as you received it.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks. I try to use as Web api get method. I think I can figure it out.

Comment: As a note on code, it looks like you're injecting values into the query string, rather than using `WithParameter` to safely create a new `QueryDefinition` with user-provided parameter values. This is the classic smell of injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET Core, an approach I've used to make the continuation token safe for round-tripping as a URL parameter is to leverage `Base64UrlEncode`.

To encode before returning to client:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
...

string continuationToken = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cosmosToken));
```

To decode when provided by client:

```
// Decode continuation token if provided
string? currentContinuationToken = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationToken) 
    ? Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(continuationToken)) 
    : null;
```

Comment: I also do the same but instead of passing the base64 encode token in query string, I pass the value as request header. This is to overcome the limitation of URL length as we don't know how large the continuation token value will be.

Comment: Good point. I've only seen tokens at a few hundred characters, but haven't seen anything that documents guarantees about length.

Comment: @NoahStahl Thanks for the answer. I figure out why I am wrong. I will take your advice to secure the token.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. I found what was the problem.

The problem was a continuation token return on JSON.

```
{  "key": "[{\"token\":\"+RID:~6XYNAPAaNywkAQAAAAAAAA==#RT:1#TRC:2#RTD:EOhlC3LmlrnZoy5QrRcNBMHZH43PLA==#ISV:2#IEO:65567#QCF:7#FPC:AgEAAAAyAK8A4Hf99T7xxMAf+QH8/AF/APwPeEB/nWZk+H8A8H8ACMAA8P//A5Dw///f/v////8B\",\"range\":{\"min\":\"\",\"max\":\"FF\"}}]",
```

When continuation token return to json, token has "\" compaier to original contiuation token. So I remove all "\" and try again it works.